# Skip first row when overwriting the CSV file in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I need help with skipping the first row when i overwrite the file. Because i get the date over the first row where i want to put a headers. Like date name etc .
I tried with `continue;` , but its not working .

```
$result =[];
foreach($sumArray as $key => $totalItems)   {
    $result[$totalItems][ ]= $sumArray1[$key];
    $timeNeeded = implode(" ", $result[$totalItems]);
    list($id1, $name1) = explode('_', $key);
    $rows = 0;

    $procenti = round(($perMin*$totalItems)/($timeNeeded/$precentEff),2);
    $procentiCon = $procenti . " %";
    $pickingEffRes = [$name1 , $totalItems, $procentiCon];
    
    if($rows == 1) continue;
    
    fputcsv($out, $pickingEffRes);
    $rows++;
}
```

Comment: `$rows = 0;` should be outside the `foreach` loop

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result =[];
$rows = 0;

foreach($sumArray as $key => $totalItems)   {
    $result[$totalItems][ ]= $sumArray1[$key];
    $timeNeeded = implode(" ", $result[$totalItems]);
    list($id1, $name1) = explode('_', $key);

    $procenti = round(($perMin*$totalItems)/($timeNeeded/$precentEff),2);
    $procentiCon = $procenti . " %";
    $pickingEffRes = [$name1 , $totalItems, $procentiCon];
    
    if($rows == 1) continue;
    
    fputcsv($out, $pickingEffRes);
    $rows++;
}
```